# How to close an activity from a custom dialog Class?

Tags: android, class, android-activity, dialog

I have an `AlertDialogUtils` class that generates an `AlertDialog` such that it can be called from any activity when an error occurs. The issue is that I cannot call `finish()` from within the `createDialog()` method as a `onClickListener` for a "dismiss" button.

Any thoughts how this may be possible?

Code for AlertDialogUtils class:

```
public class AlertDialogUtils extends Dialog {

    private Context mContext;

    public AlertDialogUtils(Context context) {
        super(context);
        mContext = context;
    }

    public void CreateAlertDialog(String errorMessage) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
        builder.setMessage(errorMessage)
            .setCancelable(true)
            .setNeutralButton("Dismiss", new AlertDialog.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    mContext.finish(); 
                    //error here. Intend to close the activtiy that created this dialog and has the error
                }
            });
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.setOwnerActivity((Activity)mContext); 
        // The dialog utils is outside an activity. Need to set owner
        alert.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps this isn't the most direct way of doing it, but why don't you pass the Activity as a parameter into `CreateAlertDialog(String)`?

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try it this way please? :

```
interface ICloseActivity {
void close();
}

class MyActivityToClose extends Activity implements ICloseActivity {

public void close() {
finish();
}

}

// -------

public class AlertDialogUtils extends Dialog {

    private Context mContext;

    private ICloseActivity mICloseActivity;

    public AlertDialogUtils(Context context, ICloseActivity aActivity) {
        super(context);
        mContext = context;
        mICloseActivity = aActivity;
    }

    public void CreateAlertDialog(String errorMessage) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
        builder.setMessage(errorMessage)
           .setCancelable(true)
           .setNeutralButton("Dismiss", new AlertDialog.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
               //    mContext.finish(); 
              //error here. Intend to close the activtiy that created this dialog and has the error

                //TRY THIS please:
                mICloseActivity.close();
               }
           });
    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.setOwnerActivity((Activity)mContext); 
          // The dialog utils is outside an activity. Need to set owner
    alert.show();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of passing a `Context` in the constructor, pass an `Activity`. It inherits `Context`, so you can use it anywhere you need a `Context`; at the same time, you can also call `finish()` when you need it.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the suggestions. `ICloseActivity`, unfortunately, did not work for me. I resolved the problem of finishing the activity and dismissing the dialog box in the following manner:
I changed the `CreateAlertDialog()` method as follows and created a helper function `exitActivity()`:

```
public void CreateAlertDialog(String title, String errorMessage, int alertType){
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
             builder.setTitle(title)  
        .setIcon(R.drawable.alert_icon)
        .setMessage(errorMessage)
        .setCancelable(false)
        .setPositiveButton("Dismiss", new AlertDialog.OnClickListener() {
                       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                           dismiss = true;
                           exitActivity();

                       }
                   });
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.setOwnerActivity((Activity)mContext);
            alert.show();
                }
             public void exitActivity() {
          this.getOwnerActivity().finish();
          }
```

While calling this utility, I simply set the dismiss listener and finish the activity incase it is dismissed.

```
             dialog = new AlertDialogUtils(MyActivity.this);
    dialog.setOwnerActivity(MyActivity.this);
    dialog.CreateAlertDialog(getString(R.string.no_data),       
                        getString(R.string.empty_table_message), R.id.list_view_alertType);
    dialog.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener(){
        @Override
        public void onDismiss(DialogInterface arg0) {
            finish();
        }
    });
```

In this way I can handle closing the current acitivity if required. 
Also, for activities that I didn't want to close instead of calling `exitActivity()`, I called `dialog.cancel()`:

```
               .setPositiveButton("Dismiss", new AlertDialog.OnClickListener() {
             public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                cancel();

             }
        });
```